# Date Format Without Time for Multiple Tables (Using GridView)

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, gridview

Greeting, guys!

I've watched through some topics about Date Formating, but couldn't find solution for my question:

I have a GridView, it's code is:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvTable" runat="server" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true" AutoGenerateColumns="true" 
RowStyle-Font-Bold="true" SelectedRowStyle-Font-Bold="true" 
onrowcommand="RowCommand" onrowediting="RowEditing">
<Columns>
    <asp:CommandField  ShowEditButton="true" ShowDeleteButton="true" ShowInsertButton="true" />
   <%-- <asp:BoundField DataField="Date birth" HeaderText="Date birth" DataFormatString="{0:dd.MM.yyyy}" />--%>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

It's used for 6 different tables from .mdb database. Only 2 of them have fields with date. These dates are getting displayed with time (31.12.2012 0:00:00). 
Are there any ways to make some changes in this GridView, so dates in these two tables are displayed without time? (Probably, maybe there's also something I should do with client code (aspx.cs)?)

P.S. The example of displaying a separate table:

```
<asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource3" runat="server" 
DataFile="~/Forest.mdb" DataSourceMode="DataSet" 

SelectCommand="SELECT [Worker_ID], Surname, Name, 2nd_name, [Date birth], Position FROM Lumberjacks" 

UpdateCommand="UPDATE Lumberjacks SET Surname=?, Name=?, 2nd_name=?, [Date birth]=?, Position=? WHERE ([Worker_ID]=?)"

DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM Lumberjacks WHERE ([Worker_ID]=?)"

InsertCommand="INSERT INTO Lumberjacks(Surname, Name, 2nd_name, [Date birth], Position) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)">

<UpdateParameters>
<asp:Parameter Name="Surname"/>
<asp:Parameter Name="Name"/>
<asp:Parameter Name="2nd_name"/>
<asp:Parameter Name="Date birth"/>
<asp:Parameter Name="Position"/>
<asp:Parameter Name="Worker_ID"/>
</UpdateParameters>

<DeleteParameters>
<asp:Parameter Name="Worker_ID" />
</DeleteParameters>

<InsertParameters>
<asp:Parameter Name="Surname"/>
<asp:Parameter Name="Name"/>
<asp:Parameter Name="2nd_name"/>
<asp:Parameter Name="Date birth"/>
<asp:Parameter Name="Position"/>
</InsertParameters>

</asp:AccessDataSource>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could do this from the MySQL query using the date() function? This function should remove the time from the value in the DB.

Comment: Ok, I made a change is AccessDataSource, I wrote down the SelectCommand like this:
<br>
SelectCommand="SELECT [Worker_ID], Surname, Name, 2nd_name, CONVERT(varchar(13), Date birth, 102), Position FROM Lumberjacks;
<br>
But still, there's a mistake announcing that there's a
Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression.
<br>
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try this, should remove the time from the date field before it is returned to the web page.   SelectCommand="SELECT [Worker_ID], Surname, Name, 2nd_name, date([Date birth]) AS 'Date birth', Position FROM Lumberjacks"

Comment: Ok, another error:
"Wrong number of arguments of function is query expression". 
I use OleDb Connection, if you need, by the way

Comment: Try this, I ran this query and it provided the correct results SelectCommand="SELECT Worker_ID, Surname, Name, 2nd_name, DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME('Date birth'),'%d.%m.%Y') AS 'Date birth', Position FROM Lumberjacks"

Comment: Undefined function 'DATE_FORMAT' in expression. Something is definitely wrong with this code...

Comment: Ok, let's try it another way. What if to make a SQL query in MS Access using date() function. How should it look like in MS Access query?

Comment: I ran this on MySQL 5.6 with no complaints. Without seeing the DB columns it is hard to verify, but the DATE_FORMAT() function will work in this instance, provided your column data type is datetime. Check out [DATE_FORMAT()](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp) should help

Comment: Ok, let's try it another way. What if to make a SQL query in MS Access? I've found Format() function. Maybe this could be solution?

Comment: **Yes! Yes! Yes! I found a solution! I wrote it in a SelectCommand like this:**
*Format([Date birth], 'dd.mm.yyyy') AS [Date birth]*. ***It worked!!!***
**Thank you, Laslos, you gave me very strong assistance!**

Comment: Ok, so you are using MS Access, I saw you had the MySQL DB tagged so I was giving you MySQL queries.. no wonder it wasn't working :) I am not too familiar with MS Access and SQL, but I would try something like this SELECT [Worker_ID], Surname, Name, 2nd_name, DateValue([Date birth]) AS 'Date birth', Position FROM Lumberjacks"